# Best reference book for basic concepts when working with bioinformatics

Tags: book-recommendation

I'm starting to study Bioinformatics, I already have basic knowledge of Biochemistry and Genetics, but I want to buy a reference book, to use when I forget a concept (I'm a Computer Science student, not a Biotechnologist).

I have already had contact with the following two books (for basic concepts):

- Molecular Biology of the Cell, Alberts;
- Principles of Biochemistry, Lehninger.

Which is better for my use or do you have another recommendation?

I prefer a generalist book, which covers the basic concepts, and not a Bioinformatics book, which covers basic concepts in one chapter.

Comment: 1. bioinformatics has its own [stackexchange](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/) fyi. 2. bioinformatics is a huge field. what is the part of it that you want to know about? sequence alignment/assembly? structural modeling? biostatistics/clinincal trials? population genomics? generic data analysis in a biology context? pharmacology and drug development? high-dimensional data analysis./ multi-omic data integration? metabolomics? theoretical biology? energetics? imaging? microscopy? each of these might have its own foundational text! specificity is super important.